# No resource found that matches the given name [Eclipse]

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to fix a couple errors that I'm getting when trying to create a new Android Application Project in Eclipse.

The following errors occur:

```
[2016-11-17 15:22:52 - Chatter] C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2016-11-17 15:22:48 - Chatter] 
[2016-11-17 15:22:48 - Chatter] C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2016-11-17 15:22:48 - Chatter]
```

I have tried the following things:

- Imported `android-support-v7-appcompat` into the project. Also created the reference.
- Changed `project.properties > target` from `android-19` to `android-21`

My project setup:

- Minimum required SDK: `API 14`
- Target SDK: `API 21`
- Compile with: `API 21`
- Blank Activity - Default names for everything.

Comment: if you want to just skip.. delete `values-v23.xml` from project.

Comment: @sourabhbans wouldn't that have any bad impact on the project?

Comment: no it will accept the values from `value.xml` .. `values-v23.xml` is just for api level 23. if you don't need extra things for api 23 devices.. then you can ignore.

Comment: @sourabhbans I now have the problem that `R.layout.activity_main` cannot be loaded. Following error: `activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: try to clean and build.. delete `import android.R;` if exist in acivity it should be(import ur_projectname.R;). check your dpendcies again.

Comment: @sourabhbans I'm about to give up here. There are just way too many errors.

Comment: I officially give up on this one. There were about 30+ errors. Tried re-installing Eclipse and the v7 compat both gave even more errors.